# Problem with UINavigationBarItem in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I'm new to swift and I have problem with the navigation right bar item. I did the right bar item programmatically but the problem is that I did the simple code for showing the right bar item in the view controller but it does not appear at all. I don't know what is the problem?? do I have to something in the storyboard?

This is the code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
{

         super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "startOver", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(startOver))
        self.navigationItem.title = "NavigationBar"
     }

    @objc func startOver() {
        /* if let navigationController = navigationController {
             navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
         }*/
        print("start over")
     }
```

Comment: Did you make sure your View Controller is in fact inside a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: yes by using the segue root view controller to my viewController

Comment: Implement `viewDidAppear` to `print(self.navigationController)`. What does it print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]It works fine with me, you can clean the code and then try again or you need to make sure that you embed your viewController into a navigationController

Comment: thank you, I solved the problem and it was the storyboard entry point place, I didn't know that I have  to change from the viewController to the navigationController!!